# What do the brackets mean before the function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

What do the brackets mean before a function?

For example:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvHello);
```

Here the *(TextView)* part is what I have problem with. Is it something like a parameter for

```
fun <T> findViewByID(...) {...}
```

Comment: `TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvHello);` is Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some history. `findViewById` used to simply return `View`, even if the type of the found view was more specific, such as a TextView. So if you wanted to find a view and assign it to a variable with a specific type of View, you would have to *cast* it to that variable type.

Casting doesn't change the underlying object. It just tells the compiler that you promise that the underlying object already is that more specific type, so the compiler will let you treat it like the more specific type and assign it to a variable of that more specific type.

Your first block of code is Java. The class name in parentheses casts the following expression to a specific class. In Kotlin, you cast by using `as`, so it would look like:

```
myTextView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.tvHello) as TextView
```

However, in later versions of Android and in the support libraries, they changed `findViewById` to return a generic type `T` that extends View. This allows Java and Kotlin to implicitly cast the result to the type of the variable you assign the result to. So now you can just use

```
myTextView: TextView  = findViewById(R.id.tvHello)
```

and it will automatically cast to TextView for you.

When you see code like your first block of code, it probably originated from old code from before the change to `findViewById`.

Generics are a pretty big topic, and the Kotlin documentation on it is written as if you're already highly familiar with Java generics. So I recommend reading the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) on it first, even if you don't really know Java. The explanation will still help you understand what generics do.

Answer (score 0):

It's a cast.

That converts the result of `findViewByID` to `TextView`.

Note that with the latest kotlin API that isn't needed. `findViewByID` has a type parameter `T` and will automatically return an object of the view type you like.

Once, when that code was written, `findViewByID` was returning a plain `View` and callers had to cast it to the desired type.

Answer (score 0):

In this case those brackets that contain (TextView) before the function are used to specify what kind of this you should get when you are done executing the function.

If there is a possible ambiguity about the type of thing you get when you are done executing the function, you do what is called a cast. In this case we cast the returned result to (TextView).

To understand the most basic case of casting I suggest you look at how long/double/float cast in C and Java.